# SQL foreign keys & referencing other tables - consistent errors

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g

In a classic case of rookie databasing, I'm unable to get my code to work! It's a many to many relationship resolved by this intersection table.

```
CREATE TABLE logging (
songID int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES song (songID),
playlistID int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES playlist (playlistID),
PRIMARY KEY (songID , PlaylistID)
);
```

I always seem to get the error of

```
ORA-00904: "SONGID": invalid identifier
```

or

```
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
```

The current other two tables are as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE song (
songID int PRIMARY KEY,
name VARCHAR2(100)
);
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE playlist (
playlistID int PRIMARY KEY,
name VARCHAR2(100)
);
```

And I'm unsure as to how to remove this or proceed. I'm using oracle 11g.

Comment: SHow the other tables definitions

Comment: Foreign key is not a part of a column definition. Foreign key declarations should appear after all column definitions.

Comment: You get that error when creating the third table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about

```
CREATE TABLE logging (
songID int,
playlistID int,
CONSTRAINT pk_logging PRIMARY KEY (songID),
CONSTRAINT fk_logging_song FOREIGN KEY(songID) REFERENCES song(songID),
CONSTRAINT fk_logging_playlist FOREIGN KEY(playlistID) REFERENCES playlist(playlistID)
);
```

This works for me on Oracle Apex.

Comment: Apex is a programming tool, it doesn't determine how SQL commands are used. If you want to state something, mention the database version, type, or SQLPLUS version. OP has mentioned 11g.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE logging (
songID int,
playlistID int,
PRIMARY KEY (songID , PlaylistID),
FOREIGN KEY (songID) REFERENCES song (songID),
FOREIGN KEY (playlistID) REFERENCES playlist (playlistID)
);
```

Thats how mySQL object creation should be done, so you can make it this way or  how Zajonc said above me.

The way you define it, its for SQL Server / Oracle / MS Access. Quite weird its not working for you.